# Is there a way to automatically upload changed files to a server

Tags: unix, ftp, automation

Is there a Unix command, or set of commands, which will set up a watch on a local folder and automatically upload changed files to a web server.  I use Sublime with SFTP at home which does this beautifully, but at work I can't install Sublime although I can SSH, FTP etc with Terminal on their Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[entr](http://entrproject.org/) runs arbitrary commands when files change.

It can be installed on Mac OS X via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
$ brew install entr
```

Example:

```
$ find /path/to/my/repo | entr echo "Something changed"
```

Just substitute `echo "Something changed"` with your FTP uploader of choice.

The syntax for [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) would be something like this:

```
$ lftp -e "mirror -R {local dir} {remote dir}" -u {username},{password} {host}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at rsync over FTP from here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-using-rsync-with-ftp-server/